# Websphere 5.1 add SSL certificate

Tags: java, ssl, websphere

I have the following instruction: 
Import ++++ certificate (in order to allow SSL connections) – it is done in Administrative Console for the corresponding WAS profile (Security->SSL certificate and key management->Key stores and certificates->NodeDefaultTrustStore->Signer certificates). Here you can simply add the attached trkd_cert.cer (“Add” button) or get it from port (“Retrieve from port” button, host: ++++.com, port 443)

But this is valid for Websphere 6.1. 
Do somebody know how this can be done in WebSphere 5.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. 
We should use WebSphere\AppServer\bin\ikeyman.bat tool for that